# How to disable a try/except block during testing?

Tags: python, testing

I wrote a cronjob that iterates through a list of accounts and performs some web call for them (shown below):

```
for account in self.ActiveAccountFactory():
  try:
    self.logger.debug('Updating %s', account.login)
    self.update_account_from_fb(account)
    self.check_balances()
    self.check_rois()
  except Exception,e:
    self.logger.exception(traceback.format_exc())
```

Because this job is run by heroku one every 10 minutes, I do not want the entire job to fail just because one account is running into issues (it happens). I placed a try catch clause here so that this task is "fault-tolerant".

However, I noticed that when I am testing, this try/catch block is giving me cryptic problems because of the task is allowed to continue executing even though there is some serious error.

What is the best way to disable a try/except block during testing?

I've though about implementing the code directly like this:

```
for account in self.ActiveAccountFactory():
    self.logger.debug('Updating %s', account.login)
    self.update_account_from_fb(account)
    self.check_balances()
    self.check_rois()
    self.logger.exception(traceback.format_exc())
```

in my test cases but then this makes my tests very clumsy as I am copying large amounts of code over.

What should I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756180/pylint-warning-on-except-exception

Comment: Don't use blanket `except Exception`. Put proper exception handling in your code in the right places.

Comment: Add a simple `raise` to the `except` block to re-raise the original exception.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: don't swallow all exceptions using `except Exception`. It's bad design. So cut it out.

With that out of the way:

One thing you could do is setup a monkeypatch for the `logger.exception` method. Then you can handle the test however you see fit based on whether it was called, whether it's creating a mock logger, or a separate testing logger, or a custom testing logger class that stops the tests when certain exceptions occur. You could even choose to end the testing immediately by raising an error.

Here is an example using [`pytest.monkeypatch`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html). I like `pytest`'s way of doing this because they already have a predefined fixture setup for it, and no boilerplate code is required. However, there are others ways to do this as well (such as using [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) as part of the [`unitest` module](http://simeonvisser.com/posts/how-to-mock-logging-in-python.html)).

I will call your class `SomeClass`. What we will do is create a patched version of your `SomeClass` object as a fixture. The patched version will not log to the logger; instead, it will have a mock logger. Anything that happens to the logger will be recorded in the mock logger for inspection later.

```
import pytest
import unittest.mock as mock # import mock for Python 2

@pytest.fixture
def SomeClassObj_with_patched_logger(monkeypatch):
    ##### SETUP PHASE ####
    # create a basic mock logger: 
    mock_logger = mock.Mock(spec=LoggerClass)
    # patch the 'logger' attribute so that when it is called on 
    # 'some_class_instance' (which is bound to 'self' in the method)
    # things are re-routed to mock_logger
    monkeypatch.setattr('some_class_instance.logger', mock_logger)
    # now create class instance you will test with the same name
    # as the patched object
    some_class_instance = SomeClass()
    # the class object you created will now be patched
    # we can now send that patched object to any test we want
    # using the standard pytest fixture way of doing things
    yield some_class_instance
    ###### TEARDOWN PHASE #######
    # after all tests have been run, we can inspect what happened to
    # the mock logger like so: 
    print('\n#### ', mock_logger.method_calls)
```

If `call.exception` appears in the method calls of the mock logger, you know that method was called. There are a lot of other ways you could handle this as well, this is just one.

If you're using the `logging` module, `LoggerClass` should just be `logging.Logger`. Alternatively, you can just do `mock_logger = mock.Mock()`. Or, you could create your own custom testing logger class that raises an exception when its `exception` method is called. The sky is the limit!

Use your patched object in any test like so:

```
def test_something(SomeClassObj_with_patched_logger):
    # no need to do the line below really, just getting
    # a shorter variable name
    my_obj = SomeClassObj_with_patched_logger
    #### DO STUFF WITH my_obj #####
```

If you are not familiar with `pytest`, see [this training video](https://youtu.be/RcN26hznmk4?t=2079) for a little bit more in depth information.

Answer (score 0):

`try...except` blocks are difficult when you are testing because they catch and try to dispose of errors you would really rather see. As you have found out. While testing, for

```
except Exception as e:
```

(don't use `Exception,e`, it's not forward-compatible) substitute an exception type that is really unlikely to occur in your circumstances, such as

```
except AssertionError as e:
```

A text editor will do this for you (and reverse it afterwards) at the cost of a couple of mouse-clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make callables test-aware by add a `_testing=False` parameter.  Use that to code alternate pathways in the callable for when testing.  Then pass _testing=True when calling from a test file.

For the situation presented in this question, putting `if _testing: raise` in the exception body would 'uncatch' the exception.

Conditioning module level code is tricker.  To get special behavior when testing module `mod` in package `pack`, I put

```
_testing = False  # in `pack.__init__`

from pack import _testing  # in pack.mod
```

Then `test_mod` I put something like:

```
import pack
pack._testing = True
from pack import mod
```