# Pytest Assert for function which have exception block but not raises it

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

In pytest, I need to unittest a function like a()

```
def a():
    try:
        some_error_line
    except Exception,e:
        logging.debug("----")
```

How to assert the function a() which does not raises exception ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable a try/except block during testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44080350/how-to-disable-a-try-except-block-during-testing)

Comment: Do you want to check that the exception is being caught when `some_error_line` throws it?

Comment: @hoefling yeah correct, Since a() is having common Exception block, error goes into debug and not able assert in unittest